# Greece - Multiple entry visa

Tags: visas, schengen-visas

I am planning to make several trips to Europe this year.

Does Greece give multiple entry Schengen visas? Or should I go with France?

Comment: All Schengen countries should use the same rules to work out whether you are allowed a multiple entry visa. You have to apply to the country that is the main one for the first use of the visa, or if all about the same length the one where you enter on your first visit.

Answer (score 4):

Long term Schengen visa for tourist multi trips is bit difficult to obtain, unless you show them the reason of your recurring trips, and they agree, as compared to Business Multi entry Long Term Visa. In theory, all countries are supposed to follow the same rules for this C type visa.

Which embassy/country you apply, question will be decided by asking that in which country you will spend most number of days. If number of days in two or more countries are same, the first one you visit will be the one you will be applying. Applicants can't select embassies on their choice or wish.